# Golang cron runs multiple times

Tags: go, cron

I have a developed an application and created routes ( as REST api ) for different functionalities like complete a job, charge a job etc. There routes are then setup with cron to run every 10 minutes with following code.

```
package cron
import (
    "gopkg.in/robfig/cron.v2"
    "api/config"
)
func main(){
    cron.RunCron()
    NewRouter()
}

func RunCron() {
    c := cron.New()
    c.AddFunc("@every 0h10m0s", RunAutoCharge)
    c.Start()
}

func RunAutoCharge(){
    utils.ExecuteCommand("sh " +config.GetBasePath() + "sh/auto_charge_bookings.sh")
}
```

the sh file mentioned in the function contains rest api url as follows which runs when cron runs

```
#!/bin/bash
curl "127.0.0.1:8080/merchantname/auto-charge-bookings"
```

this setup works properly but charges the customers twice , on analysis I found that the api is running twice in five minutes which should not be

Please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: make sure that you do not call `RunCron()` twice.

Comment: also you can check with `ps -A` to see if you have any other hanging go process still running. Because sometimes when killing a go process it might exit in bash but it still runs in the background.

Comment: @AlexEfimov Thanks for suggestion , as a beginner I am not sure how to run ps -A. can you please guide me on this.

Comment: @VikramSingh See https://www.tecmint.com/ps-command-examples-for-linux-process-monitoring/ . Did you also triple check that your RunCron() is only called once within your program, and that you are not also calling RunAutoCharge() from somewhere else ?

Comment: Yes I checked and its called once under main()

Comment: Then I suggest you add some logging to your RunAutoCharge() function so you can see when it starts, when the call to your `auto_charge_bookings.sh` script finishes. Looking at the timestamps in that log could help you with further debugging. Since you mention you have a REST api, does that mean someone can call your REST api, and the `RunAutoCharge` function gets called from that REST API call ?

Comment: @nos Yeah it makes sense, I will try to add some logs and check if I can trace the issue. Thanks

Comment: Did you have luck?

Comment: Added some logs , waiting to for response :)

Comment: @Vikram Do you get the solution ? . I am having the same issue?

Comment: @Vikram if you solved the case , please share your findings